# Avoid nested for loops in distance comparison

Tags: algorithm, matlab, scilab

I have two lists of objects; I would like to perform operation on a given list 2 object, only if it is within the boundaries of the current list 1 object.

Something like this :

```
for k=1:size(object_list1)
    for l=1:size(object_list2)
        if euclideanDstSqt(object_list1(k).centroid,object_list2(l).centroid) < toleranceRadius then
            // do something ...
        end
    end        
end
```

what's wrong with this, is that I will check the distance every time, even for objects that are very far from each other. Is there an algorithmic smarter way to do it ? Some kind of tree maybe ?

This algorithm may then be translated into C++, therefor I have to forget about all matrix-oriented Matlab tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put the objects in list 2 into a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree) and then for objects in list 1, keep finding nearest neighbors until the distance to the next neighbor is outside the boundary.

Comment: k-d tree is a very interesting algorithm, thank you beaker. I will also use quadratic euclidean distance (instead of taking the square root).

Answer (score 0):

I may say that you always have to compute the distance. The only solution is to have the points spatially sorted, or do some kind of pre-computing. For example, create a spatial grid, and discard all the points that belong to same quadrant than any of the points.